# I'm trying to get a class to be called from a button in an action listener

Tags: java, class, constructor, jframe

I get the error -

> contructor attendanceClass1 in class attendanceClass1 cannot be
>   applied to given types; requiredl java.lang.String,java.lang.String
>   found; no arguments, actual and formal arguments lists differ in
>   length.

The button where i'm trying to call the class from -

```
JButton Class1 = new JButton();



     Class1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125,55));
        panel.setLayout(null);
        Class1.setOpaque(true);
        Class1.setContentAreaFilled(true);
        Class1.setBorderPainted(false);
        Class1.setBounds(24, 175, 125, 55);
        panel.add(Class1);
        Class1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    attendanceClass1 ac1 = new attendanceClass1();
                    frame.dispose();
                }
            }
        );
```

The class what im trying to call -

```
    import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel; 
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart; 
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.data.category.CategoryDataset; 
import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset; 
import org.jfree.ui.ApplicationFrame; 
import org.jfree.ui.RefineryUtilities; 

public class attendanceClass1 extends ApplicationFrame {

    public attendanceClass1( String applicationTitle , String chartTitle ) {
        super( applicationTitle );        
        JFreeChart barChart = ChartFactory.createBarChart(
                chartTitle,           
                "Name",            
                "% Attendance",            
                createDataset(),          
                PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,           
                true, true, false);

        ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel( barChart );        
        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension( 560 , 367 ) );        
        setContentPane( chartPanel ); 
    }

    private CategoryDataset createDataset( ) {
        final String kyle = "KYLE";        
        final String euan = "EUAN";        
        final String sam = "SAM";        
        final String K = "Kyle's";        
        final String E = "Euan's";        
        final String S = "Sam's";        
        final String safety = "safety";        
        final DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = 
            new DefaultCategoryDataset( );  

        dataset.addValue( 9.30 , kyle, K);   

        dataset.addValue(8.40, euan, E);

        dataset.addValue(8.90, sam, S);


        return dataset; 
    }

    public static void main( String[ ] args ) {
        attendanceClass1 chart = new attendanceClass1("Attendance - Class 1", 
                "Aiming to achieve 100%!");
        chart.pack( );        
        RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen( chart );        
        chart.setVisible( true ); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Take care of Java naming conventions. Class names should start uppercase character, property names with lowercase character

Comment: Please show the implementation of class `attendanceClass1 `

Comment: hasn't really solved my issue, do you have an advice on the actual problem?]#

Comment: attendanceClass1 - added

Comment: You're trying to call `new attendanceClass1();`, but your class doesn't have a constructor with no parameters.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add two Parameters here:

```
 attendanceClass1 ac1 = new attendanceClass1("String1", "String2");
```

Or you must add a constructor with no arguments to your class

```
public attendanceClass1( ) {
  ...
}
```

Take care of Java naming conventions. Class names should start uppercase character, property names with lowercase character

Comment: The class doesn't open still, it runs but the application window does not open and display.

Comment: to make the window visible after instantiate `attendanceClass1` class call `setVisible` method in ac1 object and pass true to it like this `ac1.setVisible(true);`

Answer (score 0):

as the error messages says

> constructor attendanceClass1 in class attendanceClass1 cannot be
>   applied  to given types; required java.lang.String,java.lang.String
>   found; no  arguments, actual and formal arguments lists differ in
>   length.

your class `attendanceClass1` require two strings two be supplied when you call it ..
so your mistake is that when you call it from the `addActionListener` you did pass nothing to the constructor of the class

```
 attendanceClass1 ac1 = new attendanceClass1();
```

try to pass two strings like this

```
 attendanceClass1 ac1 = new attendanceClass1("string","string");
```